# MS Dynamic CRM Online Multi to Multi relationship Add Associate record issue

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, associate

I am new to MS Dynamic CRM Online, i have the following multiple to multiple relationship setup:

Product to eMartMenu (customized entity)

on the Form of both Entities, I have added a subgrid to each other. However, I am having problem on Product's form subgrid when I clicked on the '+' Add associate button on the subgrid, it is not responding. But i have no issue doing it on my eMartMenu's form subgrid.

Note: Both "Display SearchBox" and "Display Index" have been checked.

please advise. Thanks!

Comment: did you try to remove the subgrid, publish all the customizations, add again the subgrid and publish all the customizations_

Comment: Hi, I tried, but it is still not responsive, funny is the gridview of another relationship on the same form works beautifully..